# Circle to stay fixed when resizing window

Tags: html, css, resize, geometry

I'm making a simple website with html and CSS, and I have made a div circle. When I resize the browser, it's stretched more in one direction than the other. Is it possible to make it stay a perfect circle? If so, how?

Right now, this is the code for the circle:

```
#circle
{
border-radius: 100%;
-webkit-border-radius: 100%;
-moz-border-radius: 100%;
background-color: #B64926;
width: 60%;
height: 60%;
max-width: 70%;
max-height: 70%;
min-width: 30%;
min-height: 30%;
display: block;
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can manually set the height and width of the div like:

```
<html>
<style>
.circle {
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        background: red;
        border-radius: 100%;
}
</style>
<body><div class="circle"></div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, but I would like to percentage, so the size will be relative to the resolution of the person watching the page. I added the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this complete example:

```
<html>

    <head>

        <style>
        #circle
            {
            border-radius: 100%;
            -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
            -moz-border-radius: 100%;
            background-color: #B64926;
            height: 60%;
            max-height: 70%;
            min-height: 30%;
            display: block;
            position: fixed;
            text-align: center;
            }
        </style>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {    
                $(window).resize(
                    function(){                 
                        $('#circle').width($('#circle').height());
                    }
                );

                $(window).resize();

            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="circle"></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but my intention is to keep it to html and css! So far I have index.html and stylesheet.css, and I try to keep it as simple as that :)